# "conseguiram ser resgatados" é correto?

Tags: gramática, voz-passiva

Vejamos a frase **"a Defesa Civil resgatou os pais da criança"**.  Passando para a voz passiva temos **"os pais da criança foram resgatados pela Defesa Civil"**.   Até aqui nenhum problema, resgatar é um verbo transitivo direto e a voz passiva é possível.

Mas acabei de ouvir uma reportagem sobre o deslizamento de terra em Niterói, onde a reporter dizia **"os pais do menino conseguiram ser resgatados pela Defesa Civil".**

Entendo que a frase na voz ativa seria:
-**"a Defesa Civil conseguiu resgatar os pais do menino"**.

Mas, do ponto de vista **semântico**, não consigo entender essa frase na voz passiva.  "Os pais do menino conseguiram...?"  Não, eles não conseguiram nada, quem conseguiu foi a Defesa Civil.

Minha pergunta: "a Defesa Civil conseguiu resgatar os pais do menino" admite voz passiva?  Caso não admita, qual a explicação?

EDIT - Um outro exemplo, mais claro, em que a voz passiva mudaria o significado da frase seria "A polícia conseguiu prender os bandidos".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tua frase

> (a) A Defesa Civil conseguiu *resgatar os pais do menino*

admite passiva, mas é, ainda que não muito bem sonante:

> (b) Foi conseguido pela Defesa Civil *resgatar os pais do menino*.

Não é:

> (c) Os pais do menino conseguiram ser resgatados pela Defesa Civil.

Como observaste, a frase (c) não significa o mesmo que (a) (quem consegue algo é a Defesa Civil num caso e os pais no outro). Mas (b) já significa o mesmo que (a), como se espera de uma verdadeira passiva.

O que se passa é que qualquer uma destas frases é constituída de duas orações: uma subordinante (em letra normal) e outra subordinada infinitiva (em itálico). Para formar a passiva, o complemento direto do verbo da ativa passa a sujeito na passiva. Ora, *os pais do menino* são o complemento direto apenas de *resgatar*, o verbo da oração subordinada. Logo não serve de sujeito para a passiva da frase (a) inteira. O sujeito da passiva de (a) tem de ser o complemento direto do verbo da oração subordinante (ou principal), que é *conseguir*. Este complemento direto é a oração subordinada inteira—*resgatar os pais do menino* (“a Defesa Civil conseguiu *algo*”). Logo tem de ser esta oração subordinada inteira o sujeito da passiva de (a), resultando em (b) (*algo* foi conseguido; podemos começar a frase passiva com a subordinada, mas soa-me menos mal com o sujeito no fim, como é comum neste tipo de frase; compara com “é imperioso *apurar a verdade*”).

Aliás, a frase (c) nem sequer é passiva. “Os pais do menino conseguiram [algo]” é uma construção ativa. Só a oração subordinada—*ser resgatados*—é que está na passiva.

O mesmo modo se passa com o segundo exemplo. As versões ativa e passiva são:

> (c) A polícia conseguiu *prender os bandidos*
> (d) Foi conseguido pela polícia *prender os bandidos*

---

Agora, há pares de frases aparentemente do mesmo tipo que (a) e (c), mas em que uma é mesmo a passiva da outra e têm o mesmo significado. A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, tomo II, p. 1244-6) explica o que é que faz o significado ser o mesmo ou não (negrito meu):

> Uma frase ativa com uma perífrase verbal [verbo auxiliar + verbo pleno, como *vai examinar*] é praticamente sinónima da sua contraparte passiva […] Os seguintes exemplos ilustram esta sinonímia:
>
> (31) a. O médico especialista *vai examinar* a Ana.
>         b. A Ana *vai ser examinada* pelo médico especialista.
>
> […]
>
> Em contrapartida quando se **passiviza de forma superficialmente idêntica** uma frase complexa [duas orações ou mais] com uma sequência [verbo pleno + verbo pleno no infinitivo] o resultado não é sinónimo da frase ativa, como se ilustra em (38), um exemplo semelhante a (31) exceto no primeiro verbo, que é pleno e não auxiliar:
>
> (38) a. O médico especialista *quer examinar* a Ana.
>         b. A Ana *quer ser examinada* pelo médico especialista.

A *Gramática* explica depois em grande pormenor ao longo de duas páginas que quando temos uma frase simples, constituída por uma só oração, tenha ela um verbo simples (“o médico *examina* a Ana”) ou uma perífrase verbal (“o médico *vai examinar* a Ana”), as versões ativa e passiva têm basicamente o mesmo significado. Mas que (p. 1246):

> A estrutura de (38a) [“o médico *quer examinar* a Ana”], no entanto, é mais complexa. Nesse exemplo existem dois verbos plenos, cada um deles constituindo o núcleo de duas orações distintas: uma oração subordinante, cujo núcleo é a forma verbal *quer*, e uma oração subordinada, cujo núcleo é a forma verbal *examinar* […]

E quando passivizamos uma frase complexa como se fosse uma simples, tratando o complemento direto da oração subordinada come se fosse o complemento direto da frase inteira, o resultado é alteração do significado. Foi isso que aconteceu nos teus exemplos.

Comment: Excelente.  Eu sabia que aquela voz passiva estava errada mas não conseguia entender porque.  +1

Comment: Cristalino! Como fica então a versão passiva do exemplo da Ana? "Foi querido pelo médico examinar a Ana." parece-me estranho.

Comment: @Centaurus, a frase é gramatical e faz sentido, não é é voz passiva ("os pais conseguiram [...]" é ativa). Mas faz sentido. Imagina: as autoridade julgaram que a situação dos pais não inspirava cuidados; mas ao fim de muito insistirem, os pais do menino conseguiram ser resgatados... Agora, não faço ideia se uma interpretação deste tipo faz sentido no contexto em que ouviste a frase, ou se o jornalista queria dizer que a Defesa Civil conseguiu, e na pressão do momento se atrapalhou; acontece aos melhores.

Comment: @stafusa, o complemento direto em (38a) é "examinar a Ana", então passa a sujeito: "É querido pelo médico examinar a Ana". Fica horrível. Parece-me que o verbo *querer* não gosta de ser passivado. Olha mesmo com uma frase mais simples: "A Ana quer uma feijoada" --> "Uma feijoada é querida pela Ana". Quanto à tua resposta (que agora tem os comentários desativados), eu concordo com a tua interpretação semântica das várias frases; a análise sintática é que não estava bem.

Comment: Obrigado @Jacinto.

Comment: @Jacinto   Os pais do menino estavam soterrados.  Deslizamento de encosta devido às fortes chuvas, a casa onde moravam foi arrastada e ficaram soterrados. Não podiam fazer nenhum esforço para sairem.  A Defesa Civil foi retirando a lama e conseguiu resgatá-los com vida.

Comment: @Centaurus, pois, a frase não me parece fazer grande sentido nesse contexto. Bem, eles conseguiram manter-se vivos até os bombeiros chegarem até eles...